# notifyDataSetChanged(); not updating my AdapterView

Tags: java, android, sql, android-recyclerview

Instead a different activity for inserting the items I have a pop up that shows in the MainActivity so it doesnt refresh. I tried putting the notifyDataSetChanged() function in the onClickListiner of the button in the pop up but nothing.

RecyleView Adaper Code:

```
public class CustomAdapater extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapater.MyViewHolder> {

     Context context;
     private ArrayList foodID, foodName, foodPrice;
     CheckBox chkItem;

    //Constructor
    CustomAdapater(Context context, ArrayList foodID, ArrayList foodName, ArrayList foodPrice){

        //Declares to global variables that can be used in the MainAcivity
       this.context = context;
       this.foodID = foodID;
       this.foodName = foodName;
       this.foodPrice = foodPrice;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public CustomAdapater.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        //Inflates the item_row layout
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_row, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CustomAdapater.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.checkItem.setText(String.valueOf(" " + foodName.get(position)));
        holder.foodPrice_txt.setText(String.valueOf(foodPrice.get(position) + "$"));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return foodID.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView foodPrice_txt;
        CheckBox checkItem;

        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            checkItem = itemView.findViewById(R.id.chkItemRow);
            foodPrice_txt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtPriceRow);

        }
    }
    public void upDateData(){
        notifyItemInserted(foodName.size());
        notifyItemInserted(foodPrice.size());
        notifyItemInserted(foodID.size());
    }
}
```

MyDataBaseHelper.java

```
public class MyDataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private final Context context;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "FoodItem.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    //Declarations
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "my_food_items";
    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_FOOD_NAME = "food_name";
    public static final String COLUMN_FOOD_PRICE = "food_price";

    public MyDataBaseHelper(@Nullable Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        //Sql query
       String query =
               "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME +
                       " (" + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                       COLUMN_FOOD_NAME + " TEXT, " +
                       COLUMN_FOOD_PRICE + " TEXT);";

       db.execSQL(query);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
       db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
       onCreate(db);
    }

    void addFood(String name, String price){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

        cv.put(COLUMN_FOOD_NAME, name);
        cv.put(COLUMN_FOOD_PRICE, price);

        long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, cv);

        //Checks if the items have been added
        if(result == -1){
            Toast.makeText(context, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(context,"Added Successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }

    Cursor readAllData(){
        //Selects all the data from the sqlite table
        String query  = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = null;
        //Checks if there is data in the table
        if(db != null){
            //Declares all the data from the table to cursors variable
          cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        }
        return cursor;
    }

    public void clearTable() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_NAME);
    }

}
```

MainActivity code:

```
public class SecondScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

 
    Button btnAddItem;
    MyDataBaseHelper myDB;

    ArrayList<String> foodID, foodName, foodPrice;
    CustomAdapater customAdapater;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;


    //PopUp
    EditText edtFoodName;
    EditText edtFoodPrice;
    Dialog myDialog;
    Button btnAddFood;
    TextView cancel;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second_screen);

        //Declarations
        txtSeekBarPercent = findViewById(R.id.txtSeekBarProcent);
        seekBarTipPercent = findViewById(R.id.seekBarTipPercent);
        txtItems = findViewById(R.id.txtItems);
        btnRetakeImg = findViewById(R.id.btnRetake);
        btnAddItem = findViewById(R.id.btnAddItem);
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycleView);

        myDB = new MyDataBaseHelper(SecondScreen.this);
        foodID = new ArrayList<>();
        foodName = new ArrayList<>();
        foodPrice = new ArrayList<>();

        //Button for adding items
        btnAddItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                popUp();
            }
        });

        //Data from Sql Tables
        storeDataInArrays();
        customAdapater = new CustomAdapater(SecondScreen.this, foodID, foodName, foodPrice);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(SecondScreen.this));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(customAdapater);

    }

    //Storing the data from the sql table
    public void storeDataInArrays() {
        Cursor cursor = myDB.readAllData();
        //Gets the count of the rows
        if (cursor.getCount() == 0) {
            Log.i("TAG", "No data");
        } else {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                foodID.add(cursor.getString(0));
                foodName.add(cursor.getString(1));
                foodPrice.add(cursor.getString(2));
            }
        }
    }

 public void popUp() {
        myDialog = new Dialog(SecondScreen.this);
        myDialog.setContentView(R.layout.add_food_popup);
        myDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
        myDialog.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        myDialog.setCancelable(false);
        myDialog.show();

        edtFoodName = (EditText) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.edtFoodName);
        edtFoodPrice = (EditText) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.edtFoodPrice);
        btnAddFood = (Button) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.btnAddFood);
        cancel = (TextView) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.popUpCancel);

        btnAddFood.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                MyDataBaseHelper myDB = new MyDataBaseHelper(SecondScreen.this);
                myDB.addFood(edtFoodName.getText().toString().trim(), edtFoodPrice.getText().toString().trim());
                customAdaper.notifyDataSetChanged();
                
                //Dismisses the popUP
                myDialog.dismiss();


            }
        });

        cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                myDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

    }
```

There are a few answers about this problem on here but none of them worked for my specific situation.

Answer (score 0):

It is very hard to say what the problem actually is. The first thing I would advise you to do is to make a new class ex. `Food` with attributes `foodID`, `foodName` and `foodPrice`, and then make a single list of type `Food`, ex. `ArrayList<Food> foodList` which you will then pass to your adapter. Handling multiple lists in one adapter can cause different problems.